# Can a lodash template be used in Node.js to send HTML version of an email?

Tags: node.js, express, lodash

I am using Node.js to send a confirmation email when a user submits an order. I would like the email to include include all items that the user submits. The number of items will vary with each submission. I'd like the email body to include a table. Can a lodash template be used for this? Or should this be handled differently?

When I used the following code, the resulting email includes what I assume to be uncompiled code.

```
var tpl = _.template('<% _.forEach(items, function(item) { %><td><%- item %></td><% }); %>');
tpl({ 'items': ['Guitar', 'Harmonica'] });

var data = {
  from: 'support@example.com',
  to: email,
  subject: 'Your Order Confirmation',
  html: '<p>Thank you for submitting your order.</p>
      <table>
        <tr>
         <thead>
           <tr>
            <th><strong>Items</strong></th>'
               + tpl +

             // The template should insert each item here
             // <td>Guitar</td>   
             // <td>Harmonica</td> 

          '</tr>
         </thead>
        </tr>
       </table>' 
  };
```

Output in actual email sent:

```
function (obj) { obj || (obj = {}); var __t, __p = '', __e = _.escape,
__j = Array.prototype.join; function print() { __p +=
__j.call(arguments,    '') } with (obj) { _.forEach(items,
function(item) { ; __p += ' ' + __e(     item ) + ' '; }); ; } return
__p }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
tpl({ 'items': ['Guitar', 'Harmonica'] });
```

to

```
var html = tpl({ 'items': ['Guitar', 'Harmonica'] });
```

and

```
ng>Items</strong></th>'
               + tpl +
```

to

```
ng>Items</strong></th>'


  + html +
```

if you look at the docs at: https://lodash.com/docs#template
you will see the compiled function returns an output which you need to use.
You instead of using the output, you used the actual function itself.